# How to code this condition in Python? I am new to python

Tags: python

I am new to python. so any help will be appreciated.
I have two arrays  `A = [1,2,4,2,3,5,3]` and `B = [0,4,4,4,1,1,1]`
for the function if I give A, B as input then I should get output as = `[1,(2+4+2),(3+5+3)] = [1,8,11]`(if numbers are repeating in B then corresponding  values in A should be added together).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def bla(list1:list, list2:list):
   prev = list2[0] - 1
   final_list = []
   for ele, pos in zip(list1, list2):
      if prev != pos:
          final_list.append(ele)
      else:
          final_list[-1] += ele
      prev = pos
   return final_list
```